# android google.play bag report

Tags: android, widget, google-play, crash-reports

I've put an app in google play and recieved bag report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
com.analogclocksmiles2.WidgetActivity: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2287)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:224)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:191)
at com.analogclocksmiles2.WidgetActivity.updateWidget(WidgetActivity.java:197)
at com.analogclocksmiles2.WidgetActivity.onUpdate(WidgetActivity.java:98)
at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2280)
... 10 more
```

How can I find that place in my code?

Everything work good on emulator, but when I install my app from the market, SOMETIME widget doesn't appear in widget list of my phone.

I did override an onUpdate in widget activity:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(
            ConfigActivity.WIDGET_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
            updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, sp, id);     
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you override the "onUpdate(..)" method?

Comment: i did override an onUpdate in widget activity